# Docker install in centos 7.4 with version info failed

Tags: docker, yum, version-control

I try to use

```
yum install docker-ce-3:25.0.4-1.el7   #the current version
```

to install, It saids no package docker-ce-3:25.0.4-1.el7 available.

but if I remove the version info,just type

```
yum install docker-ce
```

it works, it could prompt me all info and ask me to type y/n to continue.

if I use `yum list docker-ce` I can see that version available.

Actually I want to install version 25.0.3 but failed with the same info, so I tried the latest version, still failed, but I can install the latest version if I remove version info.

Does anyone know how to install with version info attached? Did I type the info correctly?

Comment: Is that _really_ what the package is called though? I’m not familiar with RPM distros, but the package name (in Docker’s package feed) is _docker-ce_, the version is _25.0.3_ and the release is _1.el7_, wouldn’t you use _yum install docker-ce-25.0.3-1.el7_? Where do you get the _-3:_ from?

Comment: I use the command yum list `docker-ce`, and get the version number `3:25.0.4-1.el7`; And the official site's document tell me to use name-version to install. I think I tried the version without 3:, it still not work, but I can try one more time today. @Daniel B

Comment: @Daniel B I think you are right, it succeed with 3: removed, I tried one afternoon yesterday and didn't find it, frustrating, so why they add some thing not needed in the version number...

Answer (score 1):

```
yum clean all
```

After seeing your question, I started a docker container with CentOS 7.4 and I faced the same issue. Just a little bit of search, and I found this [link](https://forums.centos.org/viewtopic.php?t=16608) which solved the issue. All you have to do is to run `yum clean all`.

This command cleans cache for repos as well as reset their metadata. I guess this is solving the issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
yum install docker-ce-25.0.4-1.el7
```

works(removed 3:),I don't know why they add some prefix in the version number but when update/installation that prefix won't get recognized.